# How to filter button tap with button title in RxSwift?

Tags: rx-swift, reactive-extensions-js

Is there anyway we can filter button tap event based on button title like below..!!

```
button.rx.tap
 .filter { ($0.titleLabel.text.count)!> 0 }
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have provided? It should work. Isn’t that working?

Comment: @Zich no it is not working, I have just added to have clear side on question

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way to do it, but it isn't a correct thing to do. You programmatically changed the button title so the code that does that should be referenced here. Don't use your view as if it was a model.

For example:

```
func example(title: Observable<String>, button: UIButton, bag: DisposeBag) -> Observable<String> {
    title
        .bind(to: button.rx.title(for: .normal))
        .disposed(by: bag)

    return button.rx.tap
        .withLatestFrom(title)
        .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally was able to do as below, not sure where its perfect or not but serve purpose though..!!!

```
 button.rx.tap
                  .map(return button.titleLabel?.text!.lowercased()!)
                        .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: "")
                        .drive(answerLabel.rx.text)
                        .disposed(by: bag)
```